# How to set router-link for a component except some parts

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I've created a card using VueJS & tailwind. There are some buttons on the card like edit & delete. I want to add a router-link on this Card Component, so that when a user clicks on the card, it opens up, but then the edit and delete buttons don't work any more and clicking on them, redirects the page too.
How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<router-link to="somewhere">
    <card-component :data="products"></card-component>
</router-link>
```

Card Component:

```
<div :key="id" v-for="(row, id) in data">
    <div>
        <img alt="Product Image"
             v-lazy="row.img_url"
             class="vs-images-hover-zoom rounded-lg p-0 h-24 w-32 object-center object-cover"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="product-name font-medium">{{ row.name }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="whitespace-no-wrap">
        <feather-icon icon="EditIcon" svgClasses="w-5 h-5 hover:text-primary stroke-current" @click="editPopup = true"/>
        <feather-icon icon="TrashIcon" svgClasses="w-5 h-5 hover:text-danger stroke-current" class="ml-2" @click="deletePopup = true"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the EditIcon and TrashIcon to be links you need to wrap those in two separate router-links. What is the purpose of the router-link wrapping the card-component? Where is it meant to go?

Comment: @LannyBose it is meant to go to the view page of it's product, I guess it's easier for the user to click somewhere on the card and open the view page instead of clicking on a little button.

Comment: So your original idea (clicking the Card goes to show but clicking Edit on that card goes to Edit) is doable. You just don't have any router-link to Edit in your Card Component...?

Comment: You said those buttons "don't work anymore" but there isn't a link there. Did they ever work?

Comment: @LannyBose there is @ click on those buttons, but clicking on them, just redirects the page to product view.

Comment: Matheus' advice below looks good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're having trouble with [event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) because button's clicks are being caught by router-link. You can do one of them:

1. Use `@click.stop` in your buttons inside the Card component (it will stop event propagation);
2. Don't use `router-link` wrapping the whole card and put it just on image and title elements, for example;
3. Don't use `router-link` at all and get the @click event in right peaces of card, using `this.$router.push` to handle it.

Comment: I really want to keep the concept, I tried `@click.stop` but nothing changed.